# What is the correct way to write "Hello, World!" to the tangle?

Tags: transaction, tangle, data

How would a simple program look like, that, when run, writes the message *Hello World* to the tangle?

Comment: Hi Kerry! In order to get a response faster, it would help to ask a preferred programming language! I could make a "raw" request to a node using broadcastTransaction, but that would not teach you anything .)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some 'workshops' covering several hello world examples, including sending a simple non value transaction:

Javascript:
https://github.com/iota-community/javascript-iota-workshop

Python:
https://github.com/iota-community/python-iota-workshop

Go:
https://github.com/iota-community/go-iota-workshop

C:
https://github.com/iota-community/c-iota-workshop

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link about sending "Hello World" to Tangle: https://docs.iota.org/docs/client-libraries/0.1/how-to-guides/js/send-your-first-bundle